# C++: How to print some text after main() exited?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
    using namespace std;

class Derived
{

public:
    Derived()
    {
        cout<< "Initialize...\n";
    }
    ~Derived()
    {
        cout<< "Finalize...\n";
    }

};
static Derived *obj=new Derived();
int main()
{
    cout<<"Main Started::\n";

}
```

I'm trying to get the output as:
**Initialize
MainStarted
Finalize**

But getting:
**Initialize
MainStarted**

I tried to debug but its not getting into destructor. So I'm unable solve this problem.

Comment: You must call delete to get into the destructor of an dynamically instanciated object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
static Derived obj;
```

instead of

```
static Derived *obj=new Derived();
```

Now you create object with new, and never call delete, thus object will never be properly deleted.
Or you can use `boost::scoped_ptr` if you need heap allocated object for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
static Derived *obj=new Derived();
```

That's a leak - the object has dynamic storage duration (since you've created it with `new`), and nothing deletes it, so it will never be destroyed.

If you want it to be destroyed automatically, then give the object static storage duration:

```
static Derived obj;
```

Alternatively, instead of defining a class with a destructor, you can use `std::atexit` to register an arbitrary function to call when the program exits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // for atexit

void goodbye() {std::cout << "Goodbye\n";}

int main() {
    std::atexit(goodbye);
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
}
```

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: If you particularly want an extra level of indirection, yes. I can't imagine why you might want that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the derived object a pointer. Since C++ is not java, there is little need for `new` in your case. But *if* you create the `Derived` on the heap, you'll have to make sure that it gets destroyed properly, by using RAII, i.e. a smart pointer. In your code you have a memory leak, the destructor of `*obj` gets never called.
Examples for how to do it right:

```
static Derived obj; //non-heap version

//C++03 auto_ptr, now deprecated:
static std::auto_ptr<Derived> obj(new Derived());

//C++11 smart pointers:
static std::unique_ptr<Derived> obj(new Derived());
static auto obj = std::make_shared<Derived>();

//Boost smart pointers, C++03 compatible:
static boost::shared_ptr<Derived> obj = boost::make_shared<Derived>();
static boost::scoped_ptr<Derived> obj(new Derived());
```

Pick one (the first, preferably).

**Edit:** But before you do any of these, you should give a really good reason for using that global variable.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `static Derived *obj=new Derived()` but instead of use `static Derived obj1` this will print as per your requirements.